# What's $\lim_{x\to \infty} p'(x)/p(x)$ if $p$ is a stable distribution?

Tags: limits, probability-distributions

Suppose $p$ is a pdf of a stable distribution. Graphically, I believe the limit $$\lim_{x\to \infty} p'(x)/p(x)$$ is zero since the graph $p$ approaches $0$ slowly but the graph becomes flat relatively quickly. However, we don't always have a nice formula for the pdf, so if the limit is indeed $0$ for stable distributions, how can it be proved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit may not be $0$. Consider the pdf of a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
It is well known that normal distributions are stable, but :

$$p(x)= \dfrac 1 {\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\dfrac {x^2} 2}$$
$$p'(x)= \dfrac {-x} {\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\dfrac {x^2} 2}$$

Then $\lim_{x\to \infty} p'(x)/p(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty} -x=-\infty$